# Javascript object unlimited methods by general

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, object, methods

Let's assume I have an object:

```
function obj(){
    this.getAll = function(){}
    this.doSome = function(){}
}
```

If I want to invoke them, of course I need to do:
obj.getAll();

Now, if I want this object to have a general method, but without specific name, like this code:

```
function obj(){
    this.getAll = function(){}
    this.doSome = function(){}
    this.x = function(){}
}
```

And by invoking obj.abc(), it will go to this.x

Is it possible to do?

Comment: `obj` is a constructor in both of your snippets and does not have an `obj.getAll` method. Did you mean to do `new obj`?

Comment: I skipped the new, I guess it's already clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) (ECMAScript 2015) to do this:

```
var handler = {
    get: function(target, name){
        return name in target ? target[name] : target.x;
    }
};

function obj() {
    this.getAll = function() {
        console.log('get all');
    }
    this.doSome = function() {
        console.log('do some');
    }
    this.x = function() {
        console.log('x');
    }
}


var p = new Proxy(new obj(), handler);

p.getAll(); // get all
p.abc(); // x
```

NOTE: this is not currently supported by all environments. See compatibility table.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming your obj is an object, but you are coding it like a function.

It should be like

```
var obj = {
    this.getAll = function(){}
    this.doSome = function(){}
    this.x = function(){}
};
```

And answering to your question, you cannot invoke a method that was not defined, because JavaScript will return you 'undefined' as the method does not exist.

Comment: Now that's a syntax error.